# Can adjectives get plural s?

Tags: grammar, nouns, adjectives, grammatical-number, inflectional-morphology

Are the following sentences correct grammatically?

1- *The war had two hundred **woundeds**.* (And not *wounded soldiers*)
2- *There are two **modals** in that sentence.* (And not *modal verbs*)

That is, can we add plural *s* to the adjectives?

Comment: In effect, your question is, Can phrases such as "wounded soldiers" and "modal verbs" become truncated so that the original noun disappears and the surviving adjectival element is treated as a (pluralizable) noun instead? As Colin Fine says, the answer is yes it can happen—but it doesn't always happen, and the instances when it will it happen are not predictable. But it seems to me that adjectives-turned-plural-nouns of the form "actives" and "passives," for example. are more common than adjectives-turned-plural-nouns of the form "undecideds," though some instances of the latter do exist.

Comment: Not in English, but in Spanish it's grammatically necessary. You would say "three reds cars", for example.  (Or technically "three cars reds," because word order is different.)

Comment: @SvenYargs: To me no adjective gets *plural ending*. When it gets, that adjective is in its *noun* form at that situation. :)

Comment: @MasonWheeler: And in my language, Kurdish, the English sentence, "three red cars" will be "Three car red." :)

Comment: They are **not** adjectives in the context.

Comment: The Q is based on incorrect parsing.

Comment: @MasonWheeler I have Spanish as mother tongue. I have a doubt. If I'm talking about "los secundarios (windings) de transformadores " should I say. Transformers secondary then as opposed to Transformers secondaries?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, adjectives in English do not take the plural ending.

Having said that, word categories are quite fluid in English, and some adjectives may be used as nouns, in which case (if they are count nouns) they will pluralise like any other noun.

"Modal" is an example, though only in technical use (linguistics and programming). General examples are "blonde" and "characteristic".

I don't know of any rules for determining which adjectives are used as nouns in this way: "wounded" is not so used, in my experience.

[There is another way in which adjectives get used as nouns, representing the mass of things or (usually) people to which the adjective applies: always with a determiner such as 'the' and never with plural ending, so it doesn't directly relate your question: "The poor, the old, the infirm". In that context "The wounded were many" is fine. ]

Comment: So, is the word *modal* a noun or an adjective or both of them? What about in my example, is it a noun?

Comment: It is both, and in that use it is a noun.

Comment: But most of dictionaries (although not all of them) offer it as only an adjective!

Comment: As I said, it is a technical term, so ordinary dictionaries may well not list it. most English speakers will not even understand what it means as an adjective, let alone understand the noun.

Comment: And in both roles (as a noun or an adjective) it means some same thing (referring to those particular types of verbs). Is it right please?

Comment: I don't know what to call *[the] wounded* other than an "adjectival noun". But it doesn't seem to work quite the same as *the meek*, in that it doesn't seem to be possible to say *[The] two hundred meek will inherit the earth*.

Comment: The adjective used as noun creates a *class*, like "the quick and the dead", hence the inability to say "The *two-hundred* meek" because "meek" there is a class-noun not an instance-noun like "apple". We have to say "Two-hundred *of* the meek."

Comment: @TimRomano. Use a determiner for the word *noun* please!

Comment: @franky: I am not sure where specifically you mean.

Comment: The adjective used as **a** noun creates a *class*, ...

Comment: @franky, strangely enough "The adjective used as noun" is grammatical. It could also have the article, but I think it would parse differently. It would be _[the adjective] [used as a noun]_, like _[the adjective] [spoken by George]_. Without the article it is a different construction, that I think parses as _the [adjective used as noun]_. I'm not sure whether "noun" is a sort of subject complement, or whether this is a special case of the coordination phenomenon seen in "husband and wife" (that somebody wrote about here a few days ago)

Comment: My Longman dictionary says the word *noun* is countable. And it's clear that it's a singular noun. As we know, most of the singular countable nouns essentially need a determiner.

Comment: It is countable and normally needs a determiner. But I have just given you one example of a construction where countable nouns do not need determiners, ("husband and wife") and referred to another "He was elected president". I'm not sure whether this case is similar to one of those or is a third, different case; but my judgment as an English speaker is that "the adjective used as noun" is grammatical.

Comment: I mention these with complete respect to your dear Colin. You helped me and I appreciate you because of it. But in this case I like to be free to state my opinion. :) To me, each singular countable noun needs a type of determiners essentially always, there are some exceptional words/idioms though. The construct *he was elected president* is not grammatical to me.

Comment: I'd use a definite article before the word *elected*. About the construct *husband and wife* I need more context to figure out the intention of that. Anyway, we can create another thread here about using the determiners and offer those constructs/sentences to hear more on this case from other experts. PS: I don't call myself an expert of course.

Comment: @franky: The phrase "adjective used as noun" is grammatical; speakers of all dialects of English would accept it and use it.  The word **as** accepts a noun without determiner, just as **without** here in this sentence does.

Comment: OK. Thanks to both of you. Apparently I need to add those two words to the list of exceptional cases! Apparently each and every rule of this English has been broken many times before! What a precise language it is! :)

Comment: @franky: But the rules are not being broken :) As Colin Fine suggested with his "elected president" example, the noun following **as** is a so-called "bare role" noun.  The complement of **as** can be a role.  The situation with **without** is more complicated.

Comment: "adjectives may be used as nouns" changes the whole game. The Q is based on incorrect parsing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a native English speaker. But, what I help you best is introducing this link to you.

http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/modal

It says that "modal" can be a noun. Having searched on the Internet, yet, I haven't found any clue about "woundeds".

Have a nice English hunting. :)