# How to use "sinister"

Tags: grammar

I am good in communication English, but very weak in grammar. I was reading the meaning of the word sinister, and I was trying to come up with a sentence with the same. What I came up with, was -

Be aware, you will always meet **sinisters** in disguise.

I wanted to know, is the above sentence correct, and more importantly is "sinisters" a right word.

tl;dr - Is "sinister + s" correct usage?

Comment: Sinister  is an adjective, you are using it as a noun, what do you mean to say? http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sinister

Comment: "When cutting meat, use your sinister hand to hold the fork and your dexter hand to hold the knife."

Comment: "Sinister is an adjective, you are using it as a noun, what do you mean to say?"

Now I understand. It cannot be used in this form as it is an adjective. I know, I seem stupid, and many of you think of this questions as lame. But if I wouldn't have asked now, I would have never understood it. Thanks a lot everybody for at least responding to my question.

Comment: Related: [Can adjectives get plural s?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/301116/can-adjectives-get-plural-s)

Comment: Sinister is traditionally an adjective; but if you want to use it as a noun, that's fine. People might complain but they don't own your usage of the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not really.  'sinisters' is not the right word when used that way.

You might say "those who are sinister" or "sinister people", but it is an adjective, not a noun.

Comment: I root caused my problem. I don't really look at the part of speech of a new word that I learn, and this explains why I asked this question at the first place. So, what I did, I came across the word sinister, looked at the meaning, and directly used it in my sentence based on how does the complete sentence sounds. Maybe, I should have been more attentive during high school. Any inputs, now as you have understood my problem, how can  I improve from here onward.

Comment: @Vijit - the parts of speech can be a bit confusing if you never learned them properly - you might be better off looking them up, and paying attention this time to how the types of words work with each other.  Otherwise, dictionaries do offer sentences which use the words when they define them, and some of the different suffixes or different forms of the word (with 's', or 'ly', or 'ness' or the like)... if studying the parts of speech doesn't work for you, you've got to get really good at picking apart the sentences they offer so you know which words stand alone, which modify others, and how.